# Loading form response into div via JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm developing an app for document collaboration. I can load the view and edit templates for sections just fine but publishing has 1 small barrier. Forms are a little different since they use an action instead of href. The response is exactly what I want (I can see it with chrome dev tools) and the response string is appending to the right div then removed upon ajaxComplete. If I treat the form action as the href, I get a missing template 500 response, in addition to the correct response.

Anyone know what the last little step is to get the form response loaded into the DOM? This is my ajax success function:

```
$('section')
.live('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  $('#' + response_str).html(data);
});
```

It's worth mentioning that show and edit use `e.preventDefault()` then use `.load()` after capturing the links href. I can't use that for publish since it would screw up the form action.

Here's my show, edit and publish functions for good measure.

```
// .live() because edit btn is an ajax loaded element
$('[id^=edit_s]').live('click', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  target = $(this).attr('href');
  sectionID = $(this).attr('id').match(/[\d]+$/);
  sectionLayer = $(this).attr('data-target');
  response_str = 'response_s' + sectionID;
  appropriateDiv.addClass(response_str);
  $("." + response_str).load(target);
});

//this could stand to be less ambigious. select the actual form for example.
$('[id^=publish_s]').live('click', function(e) {
  target = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');
  alert(target);
  appropriateDiv.addClass(response_str);
  $(this).addClass('disabled');
  //$("." + response_str).load(target); // doesn't work!
});

$('[id^=show_s]').live('click', function(e) {
  target = $(this).attr('href');
  sectionID = $(this).attr('id').match(/[\d]+$/);
  sectionLayer = $(this).attr('data-target'); // contains "#"
  appropriateDiv = $('div.tab-pane' + sectionLayer);

  // Don't need preventDefault() if tab since bootstrap does it
  if($(this).attr('data-toggle') != "tab") {
    e.preventDefault();
    appropriateDiv.removeClass('loaded');
  }

  response_str = 'response_s' + sectionID;
  if ($(appropriateDiv).hasClass('loaded')) {
    //alert("Already loaded, bro");
  } else {
    appropriateDiv.addClass(response_str + ' loaded');// ensure AJAX fills the right section
    $("." + response_str).load(target);
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a stupid mistake. In my success function, I was selecting by ID instead of class (told you it was stupid).

The reason the show and edit were working was because `.load()` includes placing the response into the selected element (duh).

Comment: This question and answer still illustrates how to get a form response into the DOM with jquery ajax. Let the form submit (don't use `e.preventDefault()`) and use `appropriateDiv.html(data)` in a ajax:success function.